# Using Spring cacheble with project reactor

Tags: spring, spring-cache, project-reactor

I'm using Spring project reactor as a reactive stream implementation, I was wondering if I can use Spring cache abstraction with reactive streams. I wanted to know if we can use those together and if anyone has solved this, how did they do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. I meant to do something for Spring Framework 5.0 and ran out of time. I really would like to resume this work for 5.1 unless someone else beats me to it.

Please watch [this issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14235) for updates.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the info!